# How to create circular reveal animation in Android API 19?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android. How to create circular reveal animation in Android API 19? I am unable to use `createCircularReveal` in API19 as it is supported only in API21.
Help me to do that in API19. I am new and need to know a lot about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find a lib for You [CIRCULAR REVEAL](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal)

Hope it helps